# Check separately if an object is an empty list | if an object not passed | if an object not list

Tags: python, python-typing

I have this function:

```
def fun(keywords: list[str] = None):
```

How to check separately:

1. if `keywords` is not passed
2. if `keywords` is an empty list
3. if `keywords` is not a list

I've tried this:

```
    if not keywords:
        raise ValueError("not passed")
    if not isinstance(keywords, list):
        raise TypeError("keywords must be an list")
    if isinstance(keywords, list) and (not bool(len(keywords))):
        raise ValueError("empty list passed")
```

First `if` runs in both cases (1. and 2.) and then in the condition

```
    if isinstance(keywords, list) and (not bool(len(keywords))):
        raise ValueError("empty list passed")
```

the code is not executed. Is it good practice to add following in first condition:

```
    if not keywords and keywords != []:
        raise ValueError("not passed")
```

Comment: `[]` is [false-y](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), so `not []` is `True`. If you want to throw an error when the value isn't passed, though, _don't define a default_.

Comment: The initial design seems to be wrong. If you need `keywords` to be passed, then make it mandatory argument `def fun(keywords: list[str]):` and shorten the checking branches

Comment: @jonrsharpe but I use `!= []` after `not []`, and it works

Comment: Because `None != []`. False-y doesn't mean "equal to `None`", it just means considered `False` in a boolean context. Fundamentally you just want `def fun(keywords: list[str]):` (which will type error on missing arguments) then the existing `if not ininstance(keywords, list):` and `if len(keywords) == 0:` (or just `if not keywords:`, but `not bool(len(keywords))` is unpleasant).

Comment: `not keywords and keywords != []` is definitely not a good check, by the way, because as well as `None` it would report "not passed" for any false-y non-list, including `0` and empty collections like `""`, `{}`, ... (also the message in a `ValueError` would generally be what value it _was_, then).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare with `None` to tell if it's not passed:

```
if keywords is None:
    raise ValueError("not passed")
if not isinstance(keywords, list):
    raise TypeError("keywords must be an list")
if not keywords:
    raise ValueError("empty list passed")
```

You don't need the `isinstance()` check in the last `if`, since the previous one already checked for that.